# Should HEAD's response status code be the same as GET's status code?

Tags: http, http-get, http-status-codes, http-method, http-head

As I know, `HEAD` is the same as `GET`, but without response body. If I request resource that doesn't exist, `GET` will response with **404 Not Found**. What status code should return `HEAD` request in this case? **200 OK** or **404 Not Found**?

Comment: You get a `status` response from the `http` request, and not from the method ! So for sure it will be 404 ! https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself, the response should be the same *except* there is no body.

This means that both the status and headers need to be the same as they would be for a `GET` request.